# Add type information to exported function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have this exported function:

```
export function foo(){

   setTimeout(function(){
     foo.x = y;                // add a property to foo fn
   },3000);

}
```

how can I declare with TypeScript that foo may have a property called "x"?

my only guess would be to do something like this:

```
   export const foo : FooType = function(){

       setTimeout(function(){
         foo.x = y;                // add a property to foo fn
       },3000);

    }
```

where FooType is an interface like:

```
interface FooType {
   foo?: YType
}
```

but I don't think that solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface should work. In fact you can add the function signature itself to the interface:

```
interface FooType {
    (): void;
    x?: string
}

export const foo: FooType = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        foo.x = "some value";
    }, 3000);
}
```